# How to achieve a left and right background split leaving middle div visible?

Tags: css

I have a `header-Container` div which stretches 100% of the width of the browser, just like on StackOverflow. Within this div is the actual `header` with a fixed width which is centered on the page.

What I want is to have a particular background colour only applied to the left side of the header, and a different colour applied to the right side of the header. I'm essentially trying to create a split background colour scheme on the `header-Container` div.

Here is a JSFiddle of where I am at the moment [**http://jsfiddle.net/1orddfn7/**](http://jsfiddle.net/1orddfn7/)

HTML:

```
<div id="header-Container">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header-Container { background-color: #CCC; position: relative; height: 190px;}
#header { background-color: red; width: 400px; height: 190px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; }
```

I can't apply two background colours and split them at the 50% mark on the header-container div (I'd like maximum browser compatibility if possible). So I was thinking that I need to create two additional divs such as `header-bg-left` and `header-bg-right` and float them left and right respectively of the main center `header` div. But then I don't understand how to make them fill the remaining space to the edge of the browser window but stop at the edge of the `header` div. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: *I can't apply two background colours and split them at the 50%*  **why??** http://jsfiddle.net/1orddfn7/1/

Comment: @Danko I didn't think it would be compatible with a lot of browsers, especially IE8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `:after` and `:before` to create elements with the color you want

```
#header-Container:before,
#header-Container:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    width:50%;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
#header-Container:before{left:0;background-color:yellow;}
#header-Container:after{right:0;background-color:green;}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/1orddfn7/2/

---

Another is to use a gradient background with two colors.

```
#header-Container { position: relative; height: 190px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #eaf700 0%, #eaf700 50%, #0fe500 50%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#eaf700), color-stop(50%,#eaf700), color-stop(50%,#0fe500));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #eaf700 0%,#eaf700 50%,#0fe500 50%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #eaf700 0%,#eaf700 50%,#0fe500 50%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #eaf700 0%,#eaf700 50%,#0fe500 50%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #eaf700 0%,#eaf700 50%,#0fe500 50%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eaf700', endColorstr='#0fe500',GradientType=1 );
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/1orddfn7/3/

(*gradient css from http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/*)

Comment: Will either of these work in most browsers? I'm not supporting IE6 and could probably ignore IE7 as well. But it must be support IE8

Comment: **note:** for the first solution you need to remove the background color on the `#header-Container` as the pseudo elements go behind it  (*`z-index:-1`*)

Comment: I really like the first example. It seems clean and neat and it works fine. Which one would you personally go with?

Comment: @volumeone you can only go with the 1st option for IE8 support